# BigQuery streaming inserts 60% fail

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to stream around 8k rows per second. So by Google's recomendations, I do that in chunks of 500 rows. Each record is 92bytes long and at the end we get around 0.9MB/s output traffic. My internet is 80Mb/s, which is 10MB/s in both directions. That should be enough.

But for some reason 60% of all request fail (no response & no new data in tables). That's how it looks:

```
Done. 173/627 which is 27.59%
{ Error: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (D:\ProgrammingNew\Actual\Idris Dos\CoinigyParser\node_modules\request\request.js:813:19)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at TLSSocket.emitTimeout (_http_client.js:708:34)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:407:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:475:11) code: 'ESOCKETTIMEDOUT', connect: false }
Done. 174/629 which is 27.66%
Done. 175/631 which is 27.73%
Done. 176/632 which is 27.85%
{ Error: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (D:\ProgrammingNew\Actual\Idris Dos\CoinigyParser\node_modules\request\request.js:813:19)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at TLSSocket.emitTimeout (_http_client.js:708:34)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:407:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:475:11) code: 'ESOCKETTIMEDOUT', connect: false }
```

Each "Done" line is logged when response from insertion is received, first number is successful requests and second one is a total amount of requests.

What can be the reason of that much requests failing?

Comment: Network issues. You need to bake logic into your application to retry such failed requests. That said, 60% sounds very high indeed.

Comment: if you open too much connections in parallel check OS limits as well